# What is the Time complexity of this algorithim?

Tags: java, isomorphism

This algorithm checks to see if 2 strings are isomorphic. ]

- Ex: Egg and add --- are isomorphic because letters map one-to-one to each other, and maintain order.
- Ex: turtle and purple --- also isomorphic.
- Ex: foo and bar -- Not isomorphic, because the second 'o' is already mapped to 'a', not 'r'.

Note: String have to be the same size to be isomorphic.

This algorithm maps the characters to an arraylist that represents each index they appear in to check for isomorphism.
I believe the space complexity is O(s.length) because the combined size of all lists is the strings.size.

What would the time complexity be? I know it is determined in the last loop where we check for list equivalency, but I can't figure it out for sure.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isIsomorphic(String s, String t) {    
        
    if (s.length() != t.length()){
        return false;
    }
     
        HashMap<Character,ArrayList<Integer>> smap = new HashMap();  
        HashMap<Character,ArrayList<Integer>> tmap = new HashMap();  
                                            
    
    
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            
           char  schar = s.charAt(i);
           char  tchar = t.charAt(i);
            
            if (!smap.containsKey(schar)){
                smap.put(schar, new ArrayList());
                smap.get(schar).add(i);
            }
        else{
            smap.get(schar).add(i); 
        }
            if (!tmap.containsKey(tchar)){
                tmap.put(tchar, new ArrayList());
                tmap.get(tchar).add(i);
            }
            
        else{
            tmap.get(tchar).add(i); 
        }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
           char schar = s.charAt(i);
           char  tchar = t.charAt(i);
            if (!smap.get(schar).equals(tmap.get(tchar))){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code iterates over the string a single time the rest of the operations cost O(N) so adding the complexities and ignoring the coefficients, the overall time complexity of the code is O(N)

Comment: is this despite the fact that for each characters in the string, the program has to iterate over the lists when using list.equals() ?